# Is there a standard size for CO2 tank nozzles?

Tags: keg, kegerator

I'm thinking of buying [this kegerator on Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004WP3ZPG), but was wondering if the smaller tank size will make it harder to find a place to fill it. Also, if I'd like a bigger tank at some point will the regulator and tubes still work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A CO2 regulator has a standard connector which would fit any size CO2 tank you'd be able to handle at the home level.

Most people start with a standard 5 lb tank.  Its about 6 inches wide, and 1.5 feet tall.  The next size up is a 20lb tank.  Its something like 2 feet tall and 8 inches wide.  Those are the most popular.

I strongly recommend finding a place that fills tanks before you buy a tank.  Near me they only do exchanges.  SO you pay a one time deposit on the tank, and then its $12 to swap said tank for each "refill".

If you do find a place that does refills, they'll have no problem filling any size tank, so I wouldn't worry about that.

Comment: Just a note - there are 10 lb tanks - I have one in my fridge now.

Comment: You know what, I meant to say 10lbs.  I am home sick today so not thinking straight.

Comment: The "standard connector" for CO2 systems is **CGA-320** (at least in the Americas), which [apparently is used for CO2 and CH3F](https://www.concoa.com/cgachart.html)